# Error AL lib: UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead. What can I do?

Tags: windows, audio

I have Win 10 and when I open Blender I have the error:

> AL lib: UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead

Comment: I have the same "error" don't worry about it. blender will work fine.

Answer (score 9):

While this is a harmless error, this is how you can fix it:

- Open user preferences with
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and go to the *[System tab](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/system.html#system)*
- In the *[sound settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/system.html#sound)*  below, change the *[sample rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)#Sampling_rate)* to 48000 kHz and
  *save user settings*
- Restart Blender

[image]

Comment: The sound settings are 48000 kHz!

Comment: ... and Blender don't work.

Comment: Nice! I never knew (or cared) how to fix that message. So simple. Now the question is why does blender default to 44100?

Comment: @David - 44100 is the [sampling rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)#Sampling_rate) used for audio cd, 48000 is the newer standard used in professional audio recording as it "works" better with multiple frame rates. When blender added audio, 44100 was probably picked as the most commonly used rate at the time and no-one has bothered to change it.

Comment: Have you tried to change sample rate to 96000hz, and then: File -> Save Startup file? What's funny, this error happens to me, but only sometimes. I just changed my sample rate and then saved the Startup File. No error.

Comment: So Blender crashes on startup and the solution is to open it and change it's settings?!

Answer (score 4):

To fix this issue you just do like in pictures
In priorities sound and set to 44100 Hz then ok and run blender , that all
[image]

Comment: This is the solution to the problem.  My device, a Dell soundbar, was set for DVD quality (48000 Hz); setting it to CD quality (44100 Hz) solved the problem.

https://imgur.com/a/Szv11

Comment: Instead of changing the system to fit Blender, why not change the Blender settings to match the system? I did and no startup error now after saving Save to Startup File.

Comment: @ejbytes that would be ideal but blender doesn't open for me because of this error so that is impossible to do

Answer (score 0):

Now, I have changed the GPU from NVIDIA high-performance processor to Integrated graphics (default). Blender works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

search sound in search box. Open it. Double click on the audio device you are using now. Then another properties box will pop up. Go to advance settings.  See 2 pics with white background in my case. Now open blender user preference. Go to system settings. Make sample rate and sample format same as the properties box which pops up previously.  In my case see the pic... 48 khz and 24 bit signed.. Then apply settings.. Then reopen the blender app.. The problem will be solved.

Comment: Use [taking screenshots](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/) instead of photos way and organize windows so that one doesn't overlap another..

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10: Log out and back in again, and Blender will start working again. (This is a solution to many (non-Blender) problems on Win10.)

I was getting the AL Lib:Update message on running a second instance of Blender. Pressed Ctrl-Alt-U, Blender crashed immediately. Could no longer run even a first instance of it.