# Blender 2.79 hz issue

Tags: audio, windows

When I try to open blender, it gives this message:

> AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead

Then it stays white and useless.

While previous answers to this issue said to change my sound to 44100hz to match Blender, my laptop only has 2 settings, both of which are 48000hz. What should I do?

Comment: The audio issue will not interfere with the usage of blender. A white screen is likely caused by some issue with the drivers for the Graphics Card. Try re-installing, uptdating or downgrading to a previous version. When asking questions like this please state what kind of hardware you are using and what Operating System. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add information.

Comment: As @cegaton suggested, the white screen is likely an issue with your graphics card. As for the issue with audio, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77857/error-al-lib-updatedeviceparams-failed-to-set-44100hz-got-48000hz-instead-wh for how to fix it.