# Trouble with commutable graphic cards

Tags: hardware

I have a laptop with commutable graphic cards (one ATI Mobile Intel Graphics = low performance, one Radeon HD 6770 M = high performance).
When I tried to run Blender on the Radeon chipset, it crashes at start.
When I try to run Blender on the Intel chipset, it runs, but slowly.

I have tried with 2.79b and 2.78c Blender version but got the same problem.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include an answer in it. The question part should only contain a question. You should post the solution as an answer even if you came up with it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the samplerate in Blender to 48'000 Hz, it works fine, as discussed [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77857/error-al-lib-updatedeviceparams-failed-to-set-44100hz-got-48000hz-instead-wh). Problem is solved.
Still don't understand why it runs correctly with only one graphic card.