# bpy loading scene from new obj file - failed to set 44100hz

Tags: python, objects, customization, audio

[image]

I saved the default cube and exported it as an obj file. I imported it in python no issue.

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=obj_path)
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
data_in=bpy.context.scene.objects.active
```

I then opened a new blender file and made a different geometry with a few modifications. I attempted to load the obj file again. An error occurs:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel

AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
Error: Not freed memory blocks: 8, total unfreed memory 0.008392 MB
```

This error only seems to happen when loading the new object into python, but sometimes it happens on the old object. How can I fix or ignore this?

Comment: Seems to be gone in newest versions of blender.

Comment: I reinstalled blender, now when I run my py file it won't connect to kernel. It works from the console though.

Comment: has nothing to do with your script, just a random message when *starting* blender

Comment: Yeah it's fixed now, after updating to blender 2.8 it just complains in parallel to doing it, how do I up-vote you? Just answer the question so I can mark it as the answer!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: My question was originally how do I fix or ignore it. I can ignore it now because the script just runs. Therefore you answered my question by advising me to update Blender to the latest version (2.8).

Comment: Nope, it's back. Reinstalling fixed it for some time, but the error has returned and is refusing to let me progress again.

Comment: Not an error rather an info and has nothing to do with your script so you can ignore it... if you can not live with that please read the answer of the linked dupe and see whether that fixes your issue: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77858/31447 in the first place

Comment: It was previously an error that prevented spyder from starting the kernel. The problem was probably due to plugging my laptop into a screen. In that link it recommended changing the audio device to 44100 Hz. This worked. Thank you.