# blender closes on startup

Tags: startup-file

I'm using an i9 desktop computer and a graphic card of Intel® UHD Graphics 630 with a Quadro rtx 4000. Currently I'm using blender 2.83 but anytime I try opening it, it shows me a black screen an it immediately closes. it doesn't open, please what do I do.
many thanks

Comment: Do other versions of blender open?

Comment: yes, blender 2.67 below which are really older version. I recently tried to get others ones to work but it keeps doing the same thing.

Comment: If all drivers are up to date, this could be an issue similar to [T72098](https://developer.blender.org/T72098). If you're using Windows try to use the workaround described in [this ticket](https://developer.blender.org/T78799).

Answer (score 1):

Start blender from a terminal.  And see if any errors show up.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/workflows/command_line.html

Platforms
How to actually execute Blender from the command line depends on the platform and where you have installed Blender. Here are basic instructions for the different platforms.

**Linux**
Open a terminal, then go to the directory where Blender is installed, and run Blender like this:

```
cd <blender installation directory>
./blender
```

If you have Blender installed in your PATH (usually when Blender is installed through a distribution package), you can simply run:

```
blender
```

**macOS**
Open the terminal application, go to the directory where Blender is installed, and run the executable within the app bundle, with commands like this:

```
cd /Applications/Blender
./blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender
```

If you need to do this often, you can make an alias so that typing just blender in the terminal works. For that you can run a command like this in the terminal (with the appropriate path).

```
echo "alias blender=/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If you then open a new terminal, the following command will work:

blender

**MS-Windows**
Open the Command Prompt, go to the directory where Blender is installed, and then run Blender:

```
cd c:\<blender installation directory>
blender
```

You can also add the Blender folder to your system PATH so that do you do not have to cd to it each time.

**You can also try to reset user preferences (this will reset blender to stock)**
https://www.katsbits.com/codex/userpref/

Comment: thanks rick, I just tried it. it told me Failed to set 48000hz, got 44100hz instead,  Error : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION Address : 0x0000000000000000. please how can I fix it

Comment: @TamiloreJoseph  Ok try the answers in this link start with the second answer first.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77857/error-al-lib-updatedeviceparams-failed-to-set-44100hz-got-48000hz-instead-wh#

And be sure to save the settings then reboot your machine.

Comment: thanks, it doesn't work either, I've tried it

Comment: Mine was actually the opposite , in the comment it was failed to set at 44100hz, got 48000hz instead. the only version that works is from 2.67 below

Comment: You may want to file a bug with the developers they are really good a narrowing it down. https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: @TamiloreJoseph -- don't forget to check the check-mark on Rick's answer if it helped you.   Some of us humbly work towards more "reputation points"!  It also helps others to find "accepted answers" that then help in solving their similar problem.